# simple XML reading in C# is not working

Tags: c#, xml

Here's my XML from which i'm trying to read:

```
<events>

<event>
    <text>You tire has a hole.</text>
    <answer cost="50">patch it</answer>
    <answer cost="100">replace it</answer>
    <answer cost="0">use your spare tire</answer>
</event>

<event>
    <text>It's your friend's birthday, everyone's going out to a fancy restaurant.</text>
    <answer cost="60">go to the restaurant</answer>
    <answer cost="30">go to the restaurant, but order something really cheap</answer>
    <answer cost="0">don't go</answer>
</event>

<event>
    <text>Your winter coat's zipper is damaged. Replacing it is costly.</text>
    <answer cost="50">replace it</answer>
    <answer cost="0">leave it like that</answer>
</event>
```

This is the code i'm trying to run:

```
    while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "text")
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadInnerXml());



                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "answer")
                        {



                            anEvent.costs[anEvent.costs.Length - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetAttribute("cost"));
                            anEvent.choices[anEvent.choices.Length - 1] = reader.ReadInnerXml();


                            Array.Resize(ref anEvent.choices, anEvent.choices.Length + 1);
                            Array.Resize(ref anEvent.costs, anEvent.costs.Length + 1);




                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "event")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("test");

                                eventsList.Add(anEvent);
                                anEvent = new Event();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

somehow, the program never gets into the last if statement. Proof, the message box "test" never runs. Everything else is fine. The array resizes are fine too (i put a message box after it to see if the program gets there). Can you guys pinpoint the mistake?

well, I fixed the problem with the help of Adam's answer. Here's the code

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("dentist_events.xml");
        bool isNotFirst = false;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "text")
            {
                if (isNotFirst)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref anEvent.choices, anEvent.choices.Length - 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref anEvent.costs, anEvent.costs.Length - 1);

                    eventsList.Add(anEvent);
                    anEvent = new Event();
                    //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                    anEvent.eventText = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                    anEvent.eventText = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                }

            }
            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "answer")
            {
                isNotFirst = true;

                //MessageBox.Show(reader.GetAttribute("cost"));
                //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadInnerXml());
                anEvent.costs[anEvent.costs.Length - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetAttribute("cost"));
                anEvent.choices[anEvent.choices.Length - 1] = reader.ReadInnerXml();

                Array.Resize(ref anEvent.choices, anEvent.choices.Length + 1);
                Array.Resize(ref anEvent.costs, anEvent.costs.Length + 1);
            }
        }

        Array.Resize(ref anEvent.choices, anEvent.choices.Length - 1);
        Array.Resize(ref anEvent.costs, anEvent.costs.Length - 1);
        eventsList.Add(anEvent);
```

Comment: Worst way of reading XML in .NET

Comment: BTW, resizing an array by one is also hugely inefficient - a list would be far preferable

Comment: @Jello because you can't actually resize an array; that means, for every item you create a new array, copy the data, and leave the old one to be collected. A `List<T>` is designed not to have that problem (by keeping spare capacity)

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean that when I resize, I lose my data? because that's not the case

Comment: Array.ReSize is very inefficient because it creates a new array of the new size, then copies all the data from the old array to the new array. What version of .NET are you using? You should be using `List<T>` instead.

Comment: ahh I see. But that's only an issue when you have a lot of data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even care about checking the end node? Once you call ReadInnerXml you are already at the end of the current element. Move 'whatever that code is' in the block you want to use at the end and simply include it after you've read the inner xml.

Answer (score 6):

`ReadInnerXml()` causes the contents to be consumed; that is why you aren't seeing anything.

Unless the xml is huge, I would recommend virtually *any other* xml processing to `XmlReader` - it isn't designed for casual use. Suggestions:

- `XmlSerializer` (loading the data into typed objects)
- `XmlDocument` (loading the data into a DOM)
- `XDocument` (same, but LINQ-to-XML)

To do this with XmlSerializer:

```
[XmlRoot("events")]
public class Events {
    [XmlElement("event")]
    public List<Event> Items {get;set;}
}
public class Answer {
    [XmlAttribute("cost")]
    public int Cost {get;set;}
    [XmlText]
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
public class Event {
    [XmlElement("answer")]
    public List<Answer> Answers {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

You can then use `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events))` to populate the fully typed model.

Comment: Amen brother... XDocument is awesome. He might have a hard time using XmlSerializer in his case because of the way his `answer` elements are laid out as an unbounded element with no container.

Comment: @Steve - not at all: `[XmlElement("answer")] public List<Answser> Answers {get;set;}` handles that

Comment: Ah, neat! I always thought it forced you to have your list/array elements within a containing element. Good to know!

Comment: which way would be the easiest?

Comment: @Jello if it was an XML *document* rather than *fragment*, i.e. if it had a single root element, then: `XmlSerializer`, easily. Very few tools are good at fragments. I recommend wrapping everything in a single `<events>` tag.

Comment: If everything is in an `<events>` tag, then you should edit your question to show that.

Comment: @Jello then XmlSerilizer is trivial - will add example